# String to NSDate conversion incorrect

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

```
NSString *str=@"2015-01-01 00:00:00”;

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];

NSDate *dtConverted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];
if (dtConverted==nil) {
    dtConverted=nil;
}
return dtConverted;
```

if my str=2015-01-01 00:00:00 then date return 2014-12-31 18:30:00 +0000
if my str=0000-00-00 00:00:00 then date return null

Please help me to resolve my problem. Need the same date as I do have in string.

Comment: You need to take timezones into account.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str= @"2015-01-01 00:00:00";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dtConverted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];
if (dtConverted==nil) {
    dtConverted=nil;
}
return dtConverted;
```

its working perfectly fine and if you want 24 hour format use HH:mm:ss instead of hh:mm:ss

Comment: now its not working have you checked/run it on your system. 2015-01-01 00:00:00 then date return 2014-12-31 18:30:00 +0000 0000-00-00 00:00:00 then date return null

Comment: check if your system time is correct.